# Reset K/D and Achievements in CS GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there any possible way to reset Kill/Death ratio and achievements earned?

I only play casual but I want to start from beginning again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you cannot reset your K/D ratio on a specific account. You can however create a new account, and start fresh. [Source.](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/828939797071758043/)

Comment: does it mean : I need to buy a new copy ?

Comment: Yes, afaik you'll need a new copy of CS:GO for a new account.

Comment: You need to create a new Steam account and buy CS:GO again